# Django REST Framework -- When using a DynamicFieldsModelSerializer the HyperlinkedIdentityField fields never get fully qualified

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

It seems for some reason when using the HyperlinkedIdentityField or HyperlinkedRelatedField in a DynamicFieldsModelSerializer the results are not fully qualified. Has anybody else run into this issue?

```
class AvailableHoursSerializer(DynamicFieldsModelSerializer):
    uri = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(
        view_name='available-hours-detail')
    staff = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(
        view_name='base-profile-detail')

    class Meta:
        model = AvailableHours
        fields = ('id', 'date', 'start_time', 'end_time', 'comments', 'active',
                  'soft_delete', 'purge', 'ctime', 'mtime', 'uri', 'staff',)
        exclude = ('purge',)
        read_only_fields = ('id', 'ctime', 'mtime',)
```

The DynamicFieldsModelSerializer is defined exactly as on the site: http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers#dynamically-modifying-fields

This is what I get:

```
HTTP 200 OK
Vary: Accept
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Allow: GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS

[
    {
        "id": 1, 
        "uri": "/api/v1/staff-profile/available-hours/1/", 
        "staff": "/api/v1/staff-profile/base-profile/1/"
    }
]
```

Notice that there is no domain proceeding the uri and staff fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently did an update to a newer version of the Django REST Framework and the newer version seemed to fix this problem. The working version is 2.3.10 and the seemingly broken version was 2.3.8. So I guess this was a bug that got fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I thinks the issue is in your DynamicFieldsModelSerializer class. If you followed the example in docs, your AvailableHoursSerializer class inherits from DynamicFieldsModelSerializer which inherits from serializers.ModelSerialize, right?

That's what documentation says as you've pointed to. But if you look at the other examples, you'll notice that the model serializer inherits from serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer in order to get fully qualified urls:

```
class AccountSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    url = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(
        view_name='account_detail',
        lookup_field='account_name'
    )
    users = serializerModelSerializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(
        view_name='user-detail',
        lookup_field='username',
        many=True,
        read_only=True
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Account
        fields = ('url', 'account_name', 'users', 'created')
```

so, using:

```
class DynamicFieldsModelSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
```

instead of:

```
class DynamicFieldsModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
```

should make you get fully qualified urls.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Having the base class as ModelSerializer should not matter as long as the individual fields use the HyperlinkedIdentityField. Using the HyperlinkedModelSerializer tends to turn everything into a hypertext field if it can, which is not usually what I have wanted. Thanks for the suggestion it did look like a logical solution.